# Microsoft Excel VBA user input on specific sheet for determining maximum value on specific sheets/rows. I am very new to VBA

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Good morning,

I am trying to sort out data from a series of values that needs to be based on user input that will determine a value greater than or equal to a maximum value on the same row.

User inputs starting minimum node for finding the maximum Ratio %

[image]

Given the minimum Node value I want to be able to find the maximum Ratio % on all of the sheets denoted with *Stresses* and return the maximum value on *Highest CC Stress Ratio* on the first image.

Here is my code:

```
Sub FindMaxIgnoringSpaces()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim maxVal As Double
    Dim aa As Range
    
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to find the maximum value
    For Each ws In Sheets
            If ws.Name Like "*Stresses*" Then

    ' Specify the target range where you want to find the maximum value
    ' Change "A1:A10" to the actual range
    Set targetRange = ws.Range("L26:L1000")
       
        
    ' Given starting Cold Case Node this will look for a value equal to or greater than
    Set aa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RUN FORMATTING").Range("C30").CurrentRegion
    


    ' Initialize maxVal with the first numeric value in the range
    For Each cell In targetRange
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
            maxVal = cell.Value
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Loop through the range and find the maximum value, ignoring spaces
    For Each cell In targetRange
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And Val(cell.Value) > maxVal Then
            maxVal = Val(cell.Value)
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Display the result
    MsgBox "Maximum value in CC stress ratio(s) is: " & maxVal
    End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

What happens is every time a window pops up and shows the maximum Ratio on each of the *Stresses* tabs, but I want it to show the maximum value it finds given the minimum node to start looking through on all of the *Stresses* tabs. Not each individual sheet, as it's completing the operation.

[image: Example of stresses tabs and what value I want the program to look through]

Apologies for the syntax and sloppy writing, I am very new to coding and want some guidance on how to orient my code for my specific needs.

Thank you so much, and if there is anything I can clarify, please ask so I can understand what's going on.

I've tried assigning values for the user input, and I cannot get it to work as intended.

```
' Given starting Cold Case Node this will look for a value equal to or greater than
    Set aa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RUN FORMATTING").Range("C30").CurrentRegion
```

I have absolutely no idea on how to change this portion of the code to display the maximum value in a specific cell. Currently a window pops up for each of the *Stresses* tabs it finds the maximum ratio value.

```
 ' Display the result
    MsgBox "Maximum value in CC stress ratio(s) is: " & maxVal
    End If
    Next
```

Comment: Please edit your post to update screenshot. Row and column heading on screenshot is important. How to determin `min node value to start`? Is it from `Sheets("RUN FORMATTING").Range("C30")`?

Comment: One question about the 2nd sceenshot, it starts from Node=30. Why it doesn't start from the upper row ( upper row to 30 with pink circle, Col A is 30 too)?

Comment: Determining the minimum node is something we have to do, but I want to use the minimum node value to create a range of ratios to find the maximum ratio within all of the stresses sheets. The minimum node is in the RUN FORMATTING sheet that we input the value into cell C30.

Comment: @taller It was just an illustration to try and convey where the program should start finding the maximum ratio value based on the given minimum node number.

Comment: My question is about `where the program should start finding`. If user input is 30, do you think the upper row (a row above 30 with pink circle) should be included in searched range?

Comment: No the program should start finding the rows <= Node 30, so not above 30, but below.

Answer (score 0):

Pls. try this:

I left out the initializing of maxVal this consolidate all sheets.

First check the column A for a value if greater then the predefined node value with the added If statement.

Fill in the Set statement the address of the cell where the starting node value is.

```
Sub FindMaxIgnoringSpaces()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim maxVal As Double
    Dim aa As Range
    Dim starting_node As Range  'added
    Set starting_node = Worksheets("name???").Range("???")  'name sheet name where starting node, range starting_node address  'added
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to find the maximum value
    For Each ws In Sheets
            If ws.Name Like "*Stresses*" Then

    ' Specify the target range where you want to find the maximum value
    ' Change "A1:A10" to the actual range
    Set targetRange = ws.Range("L26:L1000")
       
        
    ' Given starting Cold Case Node this will look for a value equal to or greater than
    Set aa = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RUN FORMATTING").Range("C30").CurrentRegion
    


    ' Initialize maxVal with the first numeric value in the range
    'For Each cell In targetRange
    '    If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then
    '        maxVal = cell.Value
    '        Exit For
    '    End If
    'Next cell

    ' Loop through the range and find the maximum value, ignoring spaces
    For Each cell In targetRange
        If cell.Offset(, -11) > starting_node Then    'added
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And Val(cell.Value) > maxVal Then
            maxVal = Val(cell.Value)
        End If
        End If    'added
    Next cell

    ' Display the result

    End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Maximum value in CC stress ratio(s) is: " & maxVal 'move here    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: The code isn't tested coz of lacking testing data.

- Getting the max value with `Application.Max` is more efficient.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub FindMaxIgnoringSpaces()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngColA As Range, rngColL As Range
    Dim cell As Range, lastRow As Long
    Dim maxValSht As Double, maxVal As Double
    Dim startNode As Long, startRow As Long
    ' Given starting Cold Case Node this will look for a value equal to or greater than
    startNode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RUN FORMATTING").Range("C30").Value
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to find the maximum value
    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Name Like "*Stresses*" Then
            ' Specify the target range where you want to find the maximum value
            ' Change "A1:A10" to the actual range
            With ws ' dynamically locate the target range
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                Set rngColA = .Range("A26:" & lastRow)
            End With
            ' Locate the start node
            startRow = 0
            For Each cell In rngColA
                If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And Len(cell.Value) > 0 Then
                    ' Get the start row#
                    If cell.Value >= startNode Then
                        startRow = cell.Row
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell
            ' Get the max ratio
            If startRow > 0 Then
                Set rngColL = ws.Range(ws.Cells(startRow, "L"), "L" & lastRow)
                maxValSht = Application.Max(rngColL)
                ' Optional: check the max value on each sheet in VBE Immediate Window
                Debug.Print "Maximum value on sheet " & ws.Name & " is: " & maxValSht
                maxVal = Application.Max(maxValSht, maxVal)
            End If
            ' Display the result
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox "Maximum value in CC stress ratio(s) is: " & maxVal
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I had to modify the code a little bit to output the result into the correct sheet. I really appreciate your help. One thing I am wondering is how did you tell the VBA to find the minimum value that we assign in the nodes? That has been very confusing for me. Again, I cannot thank you enough for the assistance.

Comment: `For Each cell In rngColA` The 1st loop is used to locate the startNode. `startRow = cell.Row    Exit For` exit the for loop as soon as find a match cell. `startRow` is the first row# of user input (start node).